# How to write CSS for parent DIV needing height dictated by child DIVs that are also anchored bottom?

Tags: css, html

Basically, I want an outer DIV's height to be dictated by its inner DIVs (specifically a *left* and *right* inner DIV) and I want any inner DIV less than that height to be anchored to the bottom of the outer DIV.

Rough sketch:

```
+=============================================+
|                                   **********|
|                                   *  multi *|
|**********                         *   line *|
|*  text  *                         *   text *|
|**********                         **********|
+=============================================+
```

I do not want to specify the height of the outer DIV, I want it to expand to its tallest inner DIV.  Also, while in some cases it might be the left inner DIV that needs to be anchored bottom with the right inner DIV dictating height, in other cases it will be the opposite with the left having taller content and the right needing to anchor bottom.

One of my attempts was to use `float:left` and `float:right` for the inner DIVs.  This nicely grew the outer DIV's height accordingly, but I couldn't find any way to get bottom anchoring for the shorter DIV.

Another attempt was to use `position:relative` for the outer DIV and `position:absolute bottom:0` for the inner DIVs (one with left:0 the other with right:0), but that only works if I give the outer DIV a fixed height instead of having it adjust to its content.

This seems like such an easy thing, and I think it would be easily doable with TABLE, but I try to avoid that at all costs.

**EDIT:**

Based on the **final suggestion** below by bookcasey, I was able to achieve what I wanted using `display:table[-row|-cell]` on my DIV elements and using `vertical-align:bottom` and `text-align:[left|right]` like you would with a table.  As in...

```
<div style="display:table;width:100%;">
  <div style="border: 1px solid;display:table-row;">
    <div style="border: 1px dotted;display:table-cell;vertical-align:bottom;text-align:left;">
    text
    </div>
    <div style="border: 1px dotted;display:table-cell;vertical-align:bottom;text-align:right;">
    multi<br />line<br />text
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reverse engineered a table into [this](http://jsfiddle.net/EAMZM/1/). With some tweaking it could work.

```
div {display:table-row;}
p {display:table-cell; vertical-align:bottom; width:125px;}
```

Comment: But he doesn't know. Either of the divs can be tallest.

Comment: book, appreciate the input, but I gotta believe there's a non-JS way?  I mean, the saying is TABLE never needs to be used for layout, but using a table would blow away having JS reassign classes just to handle a straightforward situation like this. BTW, in your second example, if you switch the text in the two DIVs, doesn't the right DIV slam over to the left since you're changing the float from right to none?

Comment: Also, FWIW, I posed my question a little more generally than my exact situation -- in my exact situation I'll know which of the two is taller at render time based on a condition I can check.  It just seemed really hackish to apply different classes based on this condition when I figured CSS could handle it more gracefully.  Disappointing if it can't.

Comment: I've got another technique, Matt!

Comment: book, thank you very much.  I wasn't even aware of the `display:table[-row|-cell]` CSS descriptions, I think that will work perfectly.  Feels a bit like cheating, but as long as it's standards compliant I'm in.  I needed to wrap my DIVs with another outer DIV to get 100% horizontal stretching instead of using fixed widths for the inner DIVs like you did.  I'll update my original post with the code that worked for me in my sandbox environment.

Comment: book, if you edit your answer to direct readers down to your final edit, I'll mark the answer as my accepted answer.  Thanks again.

Comment: Thanks again.  I've marked your answer as accepted.  I'd use the up arrows to score the post as useful, but I don't have the rep points to do it.